# how to show opened file's path in the title bar of sublime text2?

Tags: sublimetext2

when I open many files by sublime text2 ,I can not figure in which folder my open file is.

does anyone know how to show opened file's path in the title bar of sublime text2? thanks

Comment: Hovering your mouse over the tab shows the full path

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put `"show_full_path": true` is your user preferences file